# Keeping Elastic Search alive on Amazon EC2 Linux Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

I have elastic search running on a linux instance on Amazon EC2. I use tunnelier to connect to the instance. I'm new to EC2 and tunnelier (I'm more familiar with Windows Servers and Remote desktop). The problem is that when I disconnect the tunnelier console, my Elastic Search Server is no longer available for clients connecting to it. I would like to know how to keep the Elastic Search Server alive, serving client requests without my having to keep a tunnelier session active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I didn't ask this properly or so. Anyway, I found the answer here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2011/08/22/elasticsearch-on-ec2.html. Really really helpful. Thanks a million to the author. Helped me set up elastic search as a service on EC2.